# Html div id not aligning properly

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have a main div on my page that has the attribute `align="center"`, yet for some reason it is not aligning in the center.

for reference [here is the page](http://donjuma.com/dockt.php).

CSS:

```
#page{
    background-color: #4C1B1B;
    width:85%;
    height:500px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="page" align="center">
      &nbsp;
      <div id="pageleft">
        TEST
      </div>
      <div id="pageright">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin:auto` to the `#page` rule instead and remove the `align="center"`

```
#page{
   background-color: #4C1B1B;
   width:85%;
   height:500px;
   margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Plus, remove the `align="center"` - it's deprecated and can be buggy.

Answer (score 1):

```
To completely centre align the div, the following formula can be applied

left = (100 - (width of the div))/2

Using Jquery this can be done as below

var left = (100 - 85)/2;
$("#page").css("left",left + "%")
```